# Configuring Jersey 1.18.x server for JSON POJO mapping

Tags: java, json, configuration, jersey

Jersey 1.18.1 here. I have the following Jersey resource defined on my server:

```
@Path("/location")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class LocationResourceImpl implements LocationResource {
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    public LocationResourceImpl() {
        super();

        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // TODO: Configure for JSON POJO mapping how?!?
    }

    @GET
    @Path("address/{address_id}")
    @Override
    public Address getAddress(@PathParam("address_id") Long id) {
        Address address;

        address = new Address(
            1L,
            "19 ABC Dr",
            "Suite 3",
            "Testville",
            "NY",
            "US",
            "12345");

        return address;
    }
}
```

My `Address` POJO is properly annotated with `@JsonProperty` annotations. I am trying to figure out how to configure my `ObjectMapper` instance so that the `Address` instance returned by `getAddress(Long)` returns my address as JSON.

Any ideas as to what I can do? It look like `setSerializationConfig` and `setDeserializationConfig` methods were added in Jersey 2.x, but upgrading isn't an option for me, as I'm using DropWizard 0.7.1, which depends on Jersey 1.18.x.

Comment: Hmmm... with Dropwizard you don't need any extra configuration for the JSON POJO support to work. Do you mean you want to just add extra configurations to the marshalling?

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet (+1) - so can you confirm that my POJOs will be serialized/deserialized to/from JSON by default (because I am using DropWizard)? If so, that's *awesome*!, but is this documented anywhere? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet (+1) - if you get some downtime and feel like converting your comments into a quick explanation/answer, I'll happily give you the green check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Dropwizard, we don't need any special configuration for basic Jackson POJO mapping support. As explained in the [Dropwizard User Guide: How it's Glued Together](http://dropwizard.io/manual/core.html#how-it-s-glued-together):

> When your application starts up, it will spin up a Jetty HTTP server, see `DefaultServerFactory`. This server will have two handlers, one for your application port and the other for your admin port.
>
> The application port has an `HttpServlet` as well, this is composed of `DropwizardResourceConfig`, which is an extension of Jersey’s resource configuration that performs scanning to find root resource and provider classes.
>
> `DropwizardResourceConfig` is where the various `ResourceMethodDispatchAdapter` are registered to enable the following functionality:
>
> - **Enables using Jackson to parse request entities into objects and generate response entities from objects, all while performing validation**.